# Automatizar subtração de colunas no R

Tags: r

Possuo uma tabela no R de pessoas, países e dias. Preciso subtrair a quantidade de pessoas do dia anterior sobre a coluna do dia atual para todas as colunas, alguém consegue me ajudar?

Preciso fazer a seguinte formula de forma automatizada

```
05/11/20 = 05/11/20 - 04/11/20 para todas as linhas

04/11/20 = 04/11/20 - 03/11/20 para todas as linhas

03/11/20 = 03/11/20 - 02/11/20 para todas as linhas

02/11/20 = 02/11/20 - 01/11/20 para todas as linhas
```

Tentei algo assim, mas não funciona

```
mutate([c(4)] = [c(4)] - [c(4 - 1)]))
```

Depois dessa formula iria colocar dentro de um loop para alterar as colunas

No caso a primeira tabela mostra sempre o total de pessoas, preciso saber a quantidade dia a dia.

Minha base está assim:

```
Países  01/11/2020  02/11/2020  03/11/2020  04/11/2020  05/11/2020  06/11/2020

Brasil  1           1           2           3           5           7

Chile   2           2           2           4           4           5

US      0           0           0           1           2           3

México  0           0           0           0           1           1
```

Preciso dela assim:

```
Países  01/11/2020  02/11/2020  03/11/2020  04/11/2020  05/11/2020  06/11/2020

Brasil  1           0           1           1           2           2

Chile   2           0           0           2           0           1

US      0           0           0           1           1           1

México  0           0           0           0           1           0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função `diff` calcula diferença entre elementos. A função `apply` aplica uma função à uma dimensão. No caso de aplicar às linhas do *data.frame*, ela retornará uma matriz transposta, o que pode ser revertido com `t`:

```
> t(apply(dados[-1], 1, diff))
    02/11/2020 03/11/2020 04/11/2020 05/11/2020 06/11/2020
[1,]          0          1          1          2          2
[2,]          0          0          2          0          1
[3,]          0          0          1          1          1
[4,]          0          0          0          1          0
```

O `[-1]` é para não usar a primeira coluna. Para ter de volta um data.frame com os nomes:

```
cbind(dados[1], t(apply(dados[-1], 1, diff)))
```

Note que a coluna "01/11/2020" foi cortada do resultado, porque não tem cálculo de diferença para ela. Pode usar `cbind(dados[1:2], ...` para inclui-la, mas não é recomendável.

**Dados usados**

```
dados <- read.table(text = c('
  "Países" "01/11/2020" "02/11/2020" "03/11/2020" "04/11/2020" "05/11/2020" "06/11/2020"
  Brasil  1           1           2           3           5           7
  Chile   2           2           2           4           4           5
  US      0           0           0           1           2           3
  México  0           0           0           0           1           1'),
  header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode subtrair o data frame "movendo" o "dia/coluna", fazendo um slice.

Aqui temos o data frame (primeiro fatiamento)

```
df[3:ncol(df)]

  `02/11/2020` `03/11/2020` `04/11/2020` `05/11/2020` `06/11/2020`
1            1            2            3            5            7
2            2            2            4            4            5
3            0            0            1            2            3
4            0            0            0            1            1
```

E aqui temos (segundo fatiamento):

```
df[3:ncol(df) - 1]

  `01/11/2020` `02/11/2020` `03/11/2020` `04/11/2020` `05/11/2020`
1            1            1            2            3            5
2            2            2            2            4            4
3            0            0            0            1            2
4            0            0            0            0            1
```

Observe que os dois tem o mesmo tamanho.

---

Saída completa:

```
cbind.data.frame(df[1:2], df[3: ncol(df)] - df[3:ncol(df) - 1])

Países 01/11/2020 02/11/2020 03/11/2020 04/11/2020 05/11/2020 06/11/2020
Brasil          1          0          1          1          2          2
 Chile          2          0          0          2          0          1
    US          0          0          0          1          1          1
México          0          0          0          0          1          0
```